# JVM - What does "JOURNAL_FLUSHER" warning mean?

Tags: jvm

I am running an application and after a while, the logs would display

```
15:31:41 [WARN] [15:31:41.002] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3,678ms last 8 cycles average is 459ms
15:33:53 [WARN] [15:33:43.878] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 4,872ms last 8 cycles average is 609ms
15:34:48 [WARN] [15:34:40.084] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 4,941ms last 8 cycles average is 772ms
15:35:13 [WARN] [15:35:13.051] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 12,299ms last 8 cycles average is 2,306ms
15:38:19 [WARN] [15:38:13.718] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 2,366ms last 8 cycles average is 295ms
15:39:01 [WARN] [15:38:53.897] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 8,651ms last 8 cycles average is 1,377ms
```

What exactly does this mean? After a while, the application grinds to a halt and throws a heap space error. Does this mean I have to increase the heap size or the permgen size? My application runs well on another computer, however, on this one it will get exponentially slower. I am not really asking how to fix this problem, but what this warning means.

Comment: This looks like an application log.

Answer (score 1):

The JOURNAL_FLUSHER thread is responsible for writing the journal buffer to disk. These logs mean that there maybe a issue with disk performance. What is your platform (OS) and JVM settings? To fully figure out your problem, more detail information required.

Comment: My platform is CentOS 64 bit. I am not quite sure about JVM settings as I do not have full administrator access. But for the application (which is SonarQube), I did set Xmx to around 4gb. What is strange is that I have gotten "Java heap space" errors before (which I simply fix by increasing Xmx), but I have never gotten "Journal Flusher" warnings (which increasing Xmx doesn't do anything).

Comment: I do not have CentOS to simulate here. But you can check the following (1) the swap usage on the box; (2) buffer sizes configuration on the box. Since you set Xmx to 4GB, it should have no problem with the heap. As I said, performance tuning is interesting, but it requires lot of detail information to get the root cause(s).